# CKEDITOR Inline not showing NumeredList and BulletedList buttons

Tags: ckeditor, inline

I am using CKEDITOR with an Inline Setup.

I have defined my own config like that:

```
    config.toolbar_Content =
    [
        ['Undo','Redo','-','PasteText','-','Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink']
    ];
```

But the Buttons for NumberedList and BulletedList are not showing up.

If I use the local configuration page for setting up my config, the buttons are there, but not in my inline version.

What can I do?

Thanks

kay899

Comment: does someone has an idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working, the syntax is not correct.
This code should work for you. You have just to choose the right buttons.

```
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

        config.toolbar_Tiny =
        [
            { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Paste','PasteText','Undo','Redo' ] },
            { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic' ] },
            { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList' ] },
            { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },

        ];      

    };
```

Best regards.